# High dimensional Pareto dominance query data structure

Tags: data-structures, computational-geometry, pareto

I have a large (10 million+) set $X$ of  data points in some high dimensional $\mathbb{R}^d$ ($d \geq 500$) space. Each data point is quite sparse, e.g. has around $10$ components. Every missing component can be seen as having value $-\infty$ for the purposes of this problem. Associated with each data point $X_i$ is a price $y_i$.

As a quick refresher, a Pareto order is a partial order that orders vectors by those that are 'strictly better', component-wise. That is, for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^d$ we have

$$a \preceq b \iff \forall i  : a_i \leq b_i.$$

In this case we also say that $b$ *dominates* $a$ (although not strictly, $a$ and $b$ could be equal). Finally note that this is very much a *partial* order, it very often happens that $a$ and $b$ are incomparable.

Let $D(z) = \{x \in X : z \preceq x\}$ be the elements in our dataset that dominate $z$ (taking into account only the data points, not their associated prices). I wish to know if there exists an efficient data structure that can answer two things about some $z \in \mathbb{R}^d$  (even sparser, e.g. around $4$ to $5$ components):

1. the number of items that dominate $z$, or $|D(z)|$, and
2. the cheapest $k$ prices among those that dominate $z$, or the smallest $k$ elements of $\{y_i : X_i \in D(z)\}$.

Note that $k$ is small here (e.g. $10$) even though $D(z)$ might contain thousands of elements.

---

Does a data structure solving this problem efficiently exist? Every approach I can think of suffers badly from the [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality).

Comment: By any chance, do you know your queries in advance? Also, do you have some information about data distribution (e.g. if $z$ is a vector where random $10$ coordinates are not $-\infty$, then the answer is almost always $0$).

Comment: @Dmitry No, the queries are not known in advance. Some properties are much more commonly found (and queried) than others. It's however safe to assume that the queries follow the same distribution as the data set itself, but only on a large scale - individual queries might be arbitrarily different.

Comment: There is a trivial $O(|X|.d')$ running time algorithm for this problem where $d'$ denotes the number of coordinate indexes where $z$ has a non-infinite value. Are you looking for an algorithm with $O(|D(z)|.d')$ running time or even better?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Yes, that or even better (or e.g. $O(\log |X| \cdot d)$).

Comment: What about a simple thing: use masks for coordinates? For each mask, store elements from $X$ s.t. their valid coordinates contain this mask. E.g. element $(0, -\infty, 1, -\infty)$ will be stored in sets corresponding to masks $\{1, 3\}, \{1\}, \{3\}, \{\}$. Then, for each query, we simply look at elements corresponding to its mask. Why exactly it won't work?

Comment: Do you know anything about the distribution of the number of components?  If it is always exactly 10, the problem might be substantially easier in practice.  If it is always 10 or 11, it's not too bad.

Comment: @Dmitry, I like it!  I expect it'll work great if every vector has exactly 10 components.. but if the number of components varies, you also have to search over masks that are a superset of the query mask, so it requires an additional data structure for that superset query.

Comment: @D.W. The distribution is relatively tight, however $z$ is usually more sparse (e.g. 4-5).

Comment: @orlp, ooh, that seems important.  I suggest editing the question to include that information.  Your previous comment implies that the query $z$ comes from the same distribution as $X$, but it now sounds like that's not the case.

Comment: @D.W. Sorry for the confusion, in the original problem $z'$ comes from the same distribution as $X$, from which even sparser subsets $z$ are derived that are used for the queries (otherwise Dmitry's first comment would likely hold true where it's almost always $|D(z')| = 0$). The goal is to find an upper bound on the price of $z'$ if we ignore some of its irrelevant components.

Comment: I think in the database community this runs under "Skyline Queries", it may be worth searching for that term. For example, here is some research that [parallelizes skyline searches on multi-core CPUs](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/210644/files/icde2015_preprint.pdf).

Comment: @TilmannZ I looked at that paper but that just seems to be an algorithm computing the Pareto frontier (and strangely calling it the skyline, never mentioning or citing the previous works on computing Pareto frontiers). There is no equivalent of my query element $z$ or associated prices $y_i$.

Comment: @orlp Well, "skyline" is a more or less established term in the DB community. And CS communities tend to be somewhat separate and not always reading each others research. But I admit that I picked it a little bit at random just to show the "skyline" term (I did read that paper a few years ago though), sorry if it wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach you could consider.  If the number of non-missing coordinates is tightly concentrated around 10, it might help you partly avoid the curse of dimensionality.  I don't know whether it will be useful in practice.

Choose a random hash function $h:\{1,\dots,d\} \to \{1,\dots,10\}$.  If $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is a data point, let $f(x)$ be its *signature*, where $f:\mathbb{R}^d  \to \mathbb{R}^{10}$ is defined as
$$f(x) = (x^*_1,\dots,x^*_{10})$$
where $x^*_j = \max \{x_i \mid h(i)=j\}$.

Notice that the signature is dense, i.e., $f$ maps a sparse high-dimensional vector to a dense low-dimensional vector.

Also, notice that $f$ is monotonic: if $z \preceq x$ then $f(z) \preceq f(x)$.  The converse does not necessarily hold.

The approach will be to build a data structure that, given a query $z$, helps us enumerate all $z$ such that $f(z) \preceq f(x)$; then we will check each such $x$ to see whether $z \preceq x$, and count the number that do, or output the lowest-priced ones that do.  This reduces the problem from a 500-dimensional problem (on sparse data points) to a 10-dimensional problem (on dense data points).

How does the 10-dimensional data structure look?  We can use a simple trie, where the $i$th level branches on the value of $x^*_i$, and each leaf stores one data point.  In practice, I suggest organizing the list of children at the $i$th level using a binary search tree keyed on $x^*_i$, rather than as a list.

Now, the lookup algorithm simply traverses the trie recursively, but with the traversal pruned in the obvious way.  In other words, at each level we only explore the children $x^*_i$ where $z^*_i \le x^*_i$ (for query $z$).  Using the binary search tree data structure, at each level it is easy to enumerate only those children without having to enumerate the other children.

What is the running time of this algorithm?  The worst-case time could be bad, but I'll analyze the average-case running time, via an extremely crude heuristic.  If $z,x$ are two randomly chosen data vectors, then crudely $\Pr[z^*_i \le x^*_i] \approx 1/2$ for each $i$, as we have two randomly chosen numbers from $\mathbb{R}$ and it is roughly equally likely which one is larger.  Therefore, we can expect that only about a $1/2^{10}$ fraction of the data points $x$ will satisfy $f(z) \preceq f(x)$.  And, the running time of the recursive traversal of the trie will be approximately proportional to the number of such data points $x$.  Therefore, this heuristic predicts the average-case running time of this algorithm, on a random query $z$, to be something like $O(|X|/2^{10})$ time.  In other words, this is approximately a 1000-fold speedup over the naive algorithm of enumerating all data points in your dataset.  This crude analysis is overly optimistic and probably the true running time will be worse (e.g., due to collisions in the hash function, as this analysis implicitly assumed that both $z$ and $x$ have exactly 10 components and there are no collisions in the hash function, but in practice neither of those will always be true).

---

P.S. There are multiple variants possible.  We can also consider replacing 10 by an arbitrary $d'$ and optimizing over $d'$.  Also, we can alternatively define $f$ by
$$f(x) = (x^*_0,x^*_1,\dots,x^*_{d'})$$
where $x^*_0$ is the number of $x^*_1,\dots,x^*_{d'}$'s that are not $-\infty$.  I don't know whether either of those would be better, but they could be variants to try on your data set.

Another possible optimization is to precompute a dozen different copies of the data structure for a dozen different hash functions.  Then, when you want to answer a query for $z$, check which hash function maximizes the number of coordinates in $f(z)$ that are not $-\infty$, and use the corresponding data structure for the lookup.  If $x$ has exactly 10 non-missing coordinates, then it is very likely that one of these hash functions leads to a signature with only 0, 1, or 2 coordinates at $-\infty$.  Also you could consider an approach where $d'$ is large, say $d'=20$; then there is a good chance that there will be one hash function that does not introduce any collision... though I'm not sure what the effect of increasing the dimension like that might be on running time.

Comment: I like your hash idea a lot. Since we have access to $X$ in advance and can pre-compute we might even be able to choose $h, d'$ not at random but in such a way that for (almost) all $x$ if $x_i \geq -\infty$ then $\exists j: f(x)_j = x_i$. I guess that forms an interesting question in of itself.

Comment: Although I would generalize one bit, right now $x^*_1, x^*_2, \dots$ cover disjoint dimensions, this means that a dimension never gets a 'second chance' to be included. If you allow a dimension to be considered for multiple $x^*_i$ you can prevent that (possibly marking some $x^*_i$ as $\max$ nodes and others are $\min$ nodes as well).

Comment: @orlp, interesting!  I added a paragraph at the end based on your first idea.  I haven't thought about the generalization in your second comment but that is intriguing as well.

Comment: @orlp unfortunately if $z$ has only 4 non-missing coordinates, my algorithm will be much worse: at best, running time proportional to something like $|X|/16$ instead of $|X|/1000$, and maybe much worse.

Comment: No, I actually believe your algorithm (or at least the core idea behind it) works very well in practice for me, as the true worst case doesn't really affect me (if the $k$th cheapest item gets under a threshold I know $z$ isn't valuable, and I can abort early - if $|D(z)|$ is large, supply is large, and thus likely the true price is low as well). If I normalize the positions and scales of each attribute I can also get away with a very low space $f(z)$ representation (e.g. 4 bits per component).

Comment: @orlp, OK.  I'm surprised it works well, but I'm glad it does. The key might be the quantization to 4 bits or so.  You might try quantizing to equal-sized buckets (i.e., compute the distribution of that value across the entire dataset, then each bucket covers 1/16th of the percentiles) to see if that helps.

Comment: One more idea is to convert the signature to a bitmask as Dmitry suggests: $\overline{x}_i=0$ if $x^*_i=-\infty$, $=1$ otherwise.  You might map to a $d'=16$-bit bitmask (for instance), and then store $X$ in a hashmap keyed off the bitmask.  Then, given a query $z$, you get a bitmask $\overline{z}$, and you can enumerate all bitmasks $b$ that dominate $\overline{z}$ and have weight at most 10 (there will be about 1000 of them I think) and look up all data points associated with those bitmasks.  I don't know if this will be better or worse.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be also stated as a [counting version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_searching#Variations) of the [orthogonal range searching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_searching#Orthogonal_range_searching) which is well studied in computational geometry. Let us see how.

Let $m_{i}$ denote the maximum $i^{th}$ coordinate value among all the points in $X$. Then, the query of finding $|D(z)|$ can be stated as follows:

> Given an axis-parallel rectangle $R$ with the bottom left coordinate
> as $z$ and the top right coordinate as $(m_{1},m_{2}, \dotsc,m_{d})$,
> find the number of points in $X$ that lie inside $R$.

---

However, this does not answer your question accurately since in your scenario we have an added advantage that the vectors are sparse. This property can surely exploited to design more efficient algorithms.

Comment: I think orthogonal range searching algorithms are good when $d=2$ or $d=3$ but are very poor when the number of dimensions $d$ is large (such as here, where $d \ge 500$), so while it seems like a good connection, I'm not optimistic that this will help the poster in practice.

Comment: @D.W. Agreed...